# Magento meganavigation module not to display out of stock items

Tags: php, magento, megamenu

I am using a theme which includes meganavigation and has a slide out menu on the navigation where it shows a quick view of products in a category to add to the cart.

This function doesn't seem to work, so we would like to stop meganavigation from showing out of stock items altogether. I have tracked down this code:
app/code/local/Jextn/Meganavigation/Block/Meganavigation.php

```
public function cateProducts($cateId) {
    $products =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()

    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cateId))
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'asc')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->load();

    return $products;
}
```

I think we can use the addAttributeToFilter call to do this, but am having no luck. Can anyone help or send me some pointers please?

The system is on Magento ver. 1.4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stockCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_in_stock', 1);
$productIds = array();
foreach ($stockCollection as $item) {
    $productIds[] = $item->getOrigData('product_id');
}
$products =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addIdFilter($productIds)
        ...
```

[source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/27928/)

Comment: I have tried with your amended code, unfortunately it now gives me an error page on the front end - 'Invalid attribute name: is_in_stock.' with a large trace underneath.

Comment: Thanks vicch, I've used your code in a few variations but without much luck. So, for now, I am going to try an alternative solution; I will try to just hide the 'add to cart' button on said items, instead showing an 'out of stock' message. This is what my client has decided he wants.